# Get NoClassDefFoundError when implementing own jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to implement my own jar (library) in another project I'm working on. But I'm getting the error `NoClassDefFoundError` when I run the program and try to instantiate a class from the library I built.

I try to add the dependency in different ways, with maven local repo or adding the jar file directly as an external jar in Build Path. I don't get any warning/error in eclipse and I can build and install the app with maven successfully. But when I execute the part of the code that use a class from that library I get NoClassDefFoundError.

My library groupId is com.mycompany.myapp, and the classes I'm using are in the package com.mycompany.myapp.business. I'm try to move the class to the parent package just in case but I'm always getting the same error.

1 - Do I need to define which classes need to be available when importing the jar?

2- Do I need to compile the library in an specific way apart from mvn clan package/install?

3 - Do I need to add the same dependencies I have in my library in my parent project to have everything working?

This is my children pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.mylibrary</groupId>
  <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
        <version>0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
        <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
        <version>1.47</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
        <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.rpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.0-M1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

And then in my main project I instantiate the class in the following way:

```
Init oInit = new Init();
```

Where Init is a public class defined in `com.mycompany.mylibrary.business` package.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/mylibrary/business/Init
```

pom.xml from the main proyect:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany.mylibrary</groupId>
      <artifactId>mylibrary</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </dependency>
```

In the parent project, in the libraries imported by maven I see that my library has a folder icon instead of the one the other have.
[image]

Comment: You just need to add the jar to the classpath when you run the application that uses it.

Comment: Do I need to use the class path when using maven?

Comment: Depends on how you run the application.

Comment: Could you please extend your answer about when to use it and how?

Comment: Question looks very abstract, provide more details with code about how you are instantiating the class and show the project structure so that others will help you.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca the classpath should point to the jar or to the m2 repo or to the source java class?

Comment: @Sambit done! I added that information

Comment: Could you provide the error text/code
?

Comment: Where have you added the jar file containing the class com.mycompany.mylibrary.business in the above maven dependency ?

Comment: @Faabass the classpath contains either `.class` files or `.jar` files, usually, that is (in your case) you add the jar to the classpath.

Comment: @Compilerv2 the error is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mycompany/mylibrary/business/Init

Comment: @Sambit that's the library pom. The main app POM has the corresponding dependency, I added it to the post

Comment: Add your library in children pom.xml and try. Nobody can help you without knowing much details.

Comment: @Sambit what do you mean? The children project is the library... I added that to the main project as I share in my post. What other information do you need? I don't have a clue about what is causing the issue so I cannot know what to share, please tell me which information you need so I can share.

Comment: That is what I am saying, I do not understand what you are doing. Without looking into the project structure both parent and children, we can't help you. We can provide you some suggestion based upon the input.

Comment: I added all the information I consider necessary, I cannot upload the full two projects. I make 3 questions that nobody responds

Comment: can you extract your application's runnable jar/war and dig into the build/libs/mylibrary/.../Init and see if it's available there? You are getting error because it's not available.. seems it's not built properly

Comment: @VenkateshKolla-user2742897 I can validate that running `jar tvf` I can see the class listed there. I see com/mycompany/mylibrary/business/Init.class

Answer (score 0):

You can use the two ways to include a library into your project:

- Including the library directly into your project classpath
- Through Maven

When using the Maven option, you must be sure that the library is well exported to the Maven repository, local or remote (such as Nexus). The first place Maven will search when looking for a library defined in the pom.xml is on your local repository (located at `~/.m2`). The it will look into the Central Maven Repository (located at https://mvnrepository.com/repos/central). In between, you can declare your own repositories into your pom.xml as

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-repo</id>
        <name>My Maven Repository</name>
        <url>${nexus.repositories.url}</url>
    </repository>
<repositories>
```

**How to build the library to be included into your own local or remote repository?** Just be sure to include the **install** goal when compiling with Maven, and also the repository definition into its pom.xml

Comment: What do you mean with the install goal? `mvn clean install` ?

Comment: Yes, the `install` must be included in the build lifecycle https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Comment: Yes, I try that... but without success... I'm still getting the error..

Comment: Did you verified that's almost imported on your local repository?

Comment: Yes... at least I did mvn clean install and in the m2 repo folder I have the jar file and I can import the jar using maven to the main project without issues. The problem is at runtime

Comment: Have you some unit tests that can be run from your IDE, which have the same problem? This way, you can debug abd inspect more precisely

Comment: In the library I run the test and they are successful. In the main project I don’t have test... but I don’t have unit test in the main project

Comment: Add some unit tests in the main project where you instantiate the object of the library as you did in the main project

Comment: Which IDE do you use? You have to be sure not to include the same library in multiple different ways (such as Maven, adding the complete project to the classpath and adding the compiled jar to the classpath). In this case, you should privilege the Maven way, as you want a managed dependencies packaging.